# How to attach my DB.mdf?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to attach my database to my project, but I get this error:

> cannot be opened because it is version 661. This server supports version 665 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

What is this problem ?

VS2010 installed

SQL Server 2008R2 Express installed

Answer (score 2):

Those numbers seem backwards but anyway `downgrade path is not supported` is the key sentence.

Based on that error message you are trying to do something like attach a SQL Server 2008 R2 database to a SQL Server 2008 instance. That is not possible. You cannot attach a newer database `.MDF` to an older platform.

See this link for [internal version numbers](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/07/17/internal-sql-server-database-version-numbers.aspx):

Check your instance to make sure that it actually is 2008R2.

```
Select  
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') As [Version], 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') As [Level],
    SERVERPROPERTY('edition') As [Edition]
```

And then cross reference with this:

- 10.5.1600.1   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2
- 10.50.2500.0  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1
- 10.00.1600    Microsoft SQL Server 2008
- 10.00.2531.00 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP1
- 10.00.4000.00 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP2
- 10.00.5500.00 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 SP3
- 9.00.1399     Microsoft SQL Server 2005 RTM
- 9.00.2047     Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP1
- 9.00.3042     Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP2
- 9.00.3042.01  Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP2a
- 9.00.4035     Microsoft SQL Server 2005 SP3

Or look directly into your [installed instances like this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185).

Comment: its actually 2008R2. 
and if not plz send me link for it i redownload ( i am windows 7 )

Comment: Also make sure that the original MDF was express.  There may be some features from an standard, enterprise, developer MDF that will not properly attach to express.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, uninstalling your SQL Server 2008 R2 Express & installing the below should solve the issue.

Try this: 2008 R2 RTM
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=23650

If it doesn't work, try this one: 2008 R2 SP2 (LATEST)
http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30438

Good Luck!